# Redis, only allow operation on existing keys

Tags: python, redis, atomic

I am using the python package (redis-py) to operate the redis database. I have a bunch of clients that set keys and values of a hash in redis. I want they set keys and values only when the hash exists. If the hash doesn't exist, setting keys and values will create the hash, which is not what I want to do.

In the redis-py page (https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py), the author suggested a way to do atomic operation on client side. So I wrote a similar function:

```
    with r.pipeline() as pipe:
        while True:
            try:
                pipe.watch("a_hash")
                if pipe.exists("a_hash"):
                    pipe.hset("a_hash", "key", "value")                  
                break
            except redis.WatchError:
                continue
            finally:
                pipe.reset()
```

However, this seems does not work. After I delete the hash from another client, this hash still gets created by this piece of code, so I guess this piece of code is not atomic operation. Could someone help me to identify what's the problem with this code? Or is there a better to achieve this purpose?

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest to read the definition of a WATCH/MULTI/EXEC block as explained in the [Redis documentation](http://redis.io/topics/transactions).

In such block, only the commands between MULTI and EXEC are actually processed atomically (and conditionally, with an all-or-nothing semantic depending on the watch).

In your example, the EXISTS and HSET commands are not executed atomically. Actually, you don't need this atomicity: what you want is the conditional execution.

This should work better:

```
with r.pipeline() as pipe:
    while True:
        try:
            pipe.watch("a_hash")
            if pipe.exists("a_hash"):
                pipe.multi()
                pipe.hset("a_hash", "key", "value")
                pipe.execute()
            break
        except redis.WatchError:
            continue
        finally:
            pipe.reset()
```

If the key is deleted after the EXISTS but before the MULTI, the HSET will not be executed, thanks to the watch.

With Redis 2.6, a [Lua server-side script](http://redis.io/commands/eval) is probably easier to write, and more efficient.

Comment: Thanks Didier. One more question, what if the key is deleted after multi? Since redis is queueing commands after multi, is hset still executed in this situation?

Comment: If the key is deleted between the MULTI and HSET or even between the HSET and EXEC, then the MULTI/EXEC block is aborted, and the HSET not applied.

Comment: Is the reset() needed in this example?  The docs say: "If the Pipeline is used as a context manager reset() will be called automatically."

Comment: It will be called automatically - I still prefer to make it explicit.